# How to use ExoPlayer in a RecyclerView with multiple videos in the same item?

Tags: android, kotlin, video, exoplayer2.x

I know this question is repeated too much, but I haven't seen any solution to this specific scenario yet, and I need advice on how to approach this.

I basically have a list of posts (Social Network kind of posts) with multiple videos in them.
Think of it like instagram, a vertical list with posts, each post is a horizontal lists with photos, videos or both combined.

I've tried to create an activity instance of ExoPlayer and pass it down to needed adapters, however, doing so, when I change from one video to the other, horizontaly, the current playing video in the videoplayer is also shown on the next one, till the ExoPlayer gets ready to play the other video url. Much like this:

[image: Sample image 1]

Then I thought I'd make an ExoPlayer instance for each video resource and play when it is visible, while playing with the ExoPlayer release and recreation and stuff, but I started getting the *MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: **Decoder init failed*** because of the device limitation on the decoders sharing between apps.

If I should create only one instance of ExoPlayer, and pass it down the RecyclerViews hierarchy, or call it up with callbacks, **how should I fix the same video playing (like in the image attached) till the next one is ready to play?**

I don't want to fake it by putting a thumbnail on the next post till the video is loaded, because it doesn't look seamless while browsing.

Also, I have looked into a LOT of repos using the ExoPlayer on a list with mixed photos or videos, but they are all simple lists, with items having one image or video per item.

Any advice would be really helpful, thank you for your time!

Comment: Try playlist there is option available.

Comment: Playlist doesn't fit my objective. I don't want to play videos progressively, I want to be able to swipe between them, horizontally and vertically. Thank you for the suggestion!